# Issue with Binary Operator '-'

Tags: swift, uiview, binary, operator-keyword

I am receiving an odd error stating Binary operator '-' cannot be applied to two CGPoint operands in my newest build of an app I am developing. It is very perplexing as I know it can be applied as I have run the same line of code in a previous build of this app. I have tried to resolve the error by rewriting the project and get the same issue. The line of code that is causing a problem is as such:

```
    func updateRKnobWithPosition(position:CGPoint) {
       var positionToCenter = position - baseCenter
       var direction: CGPoint

       if positionToCenter == CGPointZero {
          direction = CGPointZero
       } else {
          direction = positionTOCenter.normalized()
       }
```

...

```
    delegate?.analogRControlPositionChanged(self, position: relativePosition)
       }
```

where relativePosition is a CGPoint in the class.

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong here. If it's not my code, does it have something to do with Xcode?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you weren't using it correctly earlier on. 
But if you are adamant that it was indeed working correctly before, then maybe someone or some library had an operator function working for `CGPoint`

You can create an operator function as follows

```
func - (first: CGPoint, second: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
 return CGPointMake(first.x - second.x, first.y - second.y)
}
```

Comment: Unless you are running for an Obfuscated Swift Code Contest, you should name this operator `-` and not `+` :)

Comment: There is a operator function library that contains all the operators needed to allow the analog control to function correctly, this was also included in the previous build. When I attempt the solution you gave iosDev82, i get compiler errors stating: expected declaration (in the func - line), operators are only allowed at global scope, and consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be quickly explained by looking at the documentation for `CGPoint`.  It is defined as:

```
struct CGPoint { var x: CGFloat var y: CGFloat init() init(x x: CGFloat, y y: CGFloat) }
```

So, you are asking it to subtract one structure from another and it has no idea how to do it. :)

The issue is that most of what you do in iOS and the Mac libraries is object oriented but the graphics library is notably mostly C code rather than objects with overloaded operators. :)